Loading dynamic script from API
I would like to load an external script with Vue when the page loads through an API request which delivers an HTML script with some attributes.
    <template>
        <div id="content">
          <h2>Some kinda monster</h2>
            <iframe :srcdoc="htmlContent"></iframe>
        </div>
      </template>
    
    <script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';
    
    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                htmlContent: state => state.rawhtml,
            }),
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getRawHtml();
        },
        methods:{
            getRawHtml: function() {
                this.$store.dispatch("RAW_HTML").catch(function(error) {});
            },
        },
    };
    </script>

When rendering the iframe seems completely empty. When adding the html to a static page it renders fine.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown why it's empty. It will work under normal circumstances
